# Azure Data Factory Converting Source Data Type to a Different Format

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using Azure Data Factory to copy data from an Oracle Database to ADLS Gen 2 Container

In the COPY Activity, I added Source as Oracle DB and Sink as ADLS

I want to create Parquet file in Sink

When I click on Mapping, I can see the datatype which is NUMBER in Source is getting converted as Double in ADF

Also, Date type in source is converted to DateTime in ADF

Due to which I am not able to load correct data

I even tried Typecasting in Source Query to convert it into same format as source but still ADF is converting it into Double

Pls find below screenshot as a reference:

[image: ADF Converting Number to Double]

Here ID column is NUMBER in Oracle DB, but ADF is considering it as Double and adding .0 to the data which is not what I need

Even after typecasting it to Number it is not showing correct type

What can be the possible root cause of this issue and why the Source data type is not shown in correct format

Due to this, the Parquet file which I am creating is not correct and my Synapse Table (end destination) is not able to add the data as in Synapse I have kept ID column as Int

Ideally, ADF should show the same data type as in Source

Pls let me know if you have any solution or suggestions for me to try

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Oracle user, but as I understand it the NUMBER data type is generic and can be either integer or decimal based. Parquet does not have this concept, so when it converts it basically has to be to a decimal type (such as Double) to prevent loss of data. If you really want the data to be an Integer, then you'll need to use Data Flow (instead of COPY) to cast the incoming values to an integer column.